# Yii2 ActiveRecord Setting unknown property: app\models\

Tags: php, oracle, exception, activerecord, yii2

This code throw Exception:

```
public function actionSetdubl() {
    $dubls = Yii::$app->request->post('dubl');
    $parent = Yii::$app->request->post('parent');
    $parentInfo = JurForm::find()->where(['PKJUR' => $parent])->asArray()->all()[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dubls); ++$i) {
      $val = $dubls[$i];
      $jur = JurForm::findOne($val);
      $jur->CFLDUBL = 'Yes';
      $jur->DUBLMDM_ID = $parentInfo['MDM_ID'];
      $jur->DCHANGEDATE = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $jur->save();
    }
    return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('/index.php?r=jur/analysis');
}
```

on the line with code `$jur = JurForm::findOne($val);`.

Exception:

```
Setting unknown property: app\models\JurForm::PKJUR.
```

DB: Oracle.

Comment: Have you found the solutions?

Comment: can you post the code for the model `JurForm`? is `PKJUR` defined in the model table?

Comment: either add use app\models\ModelName; at the start of controller or try app\models\JurForms::findOne($val) or app\models\JurForms::find()

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord2 has a hard time automatically mapping table names that start with a capital letter.

So for these columns you have to go into your model class and formally declare them:

```
public $PKJUR;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe better?

```
$parentInfo = JurForm::find()->where(['PKJUR' => $parent])->asArray()->one()
```

also i think  PKJUR is not defined in DB.